# How to count the number of rows updated, on each day/date, for a given range of dates

Tags: oracle, function, count

My Oracle table has columns which contain the date (timestamp) on which each row was last updated.  Column is defined as timestamp(6).

I need to count the number of rows updated on every day/date, for a given date range.
Example:  For every day in September 2016, how many rows were updated?

Example output:

```
Date                           Count                My Remarks
=================              =======              ====================
September 1, 2016                 20                20 rows updated on 9/1/16
September 2, 2016                 31                31 rows updated on 9/2/16
September 3, 2016                 14                14 rows updated on 9/3/16
September 4, 2016                 43                43 rows updated on 9/4/16
September 5, 2016                 89                89 rows updated on 9/5/16
....
September 30, 2016                74                74 rows updated on 9/30/16
```

Can anyone help me with the query?

Thanks in advance,
Rich

Comment: What îs the purpose of the MyRemarks column? How will it be populated?

Comment: The statistics will be wrong for rows that get updated several times over a period of different days.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be

```
SELECT trunc(timestamp_column)
      ,count(*)
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY trunc(timestamp_column)
```

You could, of course, create a string for the "My Remarks" column that combined the information from these two columns if that's all that column is doing (in which case I'm not sure why you'd bother...).